# why does F# complain when I write two yield! in one line?

Tags: syntax, f#, visual-studio-code

This function concats two lists together:

```
let append = fun a b -> [ yield! a
                          yield! b ]


append [1;2;3] [4;5;6]

val it : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6]
```

However, if I remove the space at the beginning of the list brackets in the function (like this `[yield! ... ]`), it no longer works.

Also if I do the followings it complains:

```
[ yield! a yield! b ]

// or this
[ yield! a
yield! b]
```

The second yield! must be right under the first otherwise it complains. Why? I understand how yield! works, but this seems a little weird to me that the syntax must be written exactly like this in this example.

Comment: The reason is that F# is a whitespace sensitive language and uses levels of indentation to identify blocks of code. Writing them both on the same line like you did is simply incorrect syntax for statements; if you put a semicolon between them, it will work, but doing that isn't very common in F# code. The second example doesn't work because the expression isn't formatted correctly due to the different levels of indentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, F# allows you to use indentation or explicit syntax in a number of places, including sequence expressions. You can put both `yield!` constructs on a single line by adding a semicolon:

```
let append a b = 
  [ yield! a; yield! b ]
```

If you are using indentation, then F# requires the statements of sequence expression to be aligned - so your `yield!` constructs have to start at the same offset. However, you do not have to indent them as far as in your first version. You can write:

```
let append a b = 
  [ yield! a
    yield! b ]
```

Another, also valid, alternative syntax (which I personally do not find that nice, but which works too) is to put the opening `[` on previous line and the closing `]` on a new line:

```
let append a b = [ 
  yield! a
  yield! b 
]
```

Note that I also replaced your `let append = fun a b ->` with an inline function definition `let append a b` - you can put the parameters immediately after the function name, rather than creating an explicit function using `fun`.

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you! Unfortunately I can't upvote yet, but I will as soon as I gain the privilege. By the way, when would it be appropriate to use the lambda fun? I'm thinking about creating a new question to ask about that.

Comment: @Later_72 You can open a new question to get a detailed answer - in short, the code using `fun` means the same thing, but is longer - so pretty much all F# code I've seen just uses the `let append a b =` style. The only difference is that editors might give you better hints in this case - because they know the names of parameters.